# How can I compile Qt app in Linux using Windows style?

Tags: qt, styles, uiappearance

I'm developing a Qt Widgets application and due to compile performance issues, I started developing it in Linux Ubuntu instead of Windows. The problems is that, when compiled and run, the app appears with traditional Ubuntu style instead of Windows (7) style. Since the app is only for Windows, I'ld like to know how can I compile it inside Linux Ubuntu but making it appear with Windows style.

I tried using `QApplication::setStyle(QStyleFactory::create("QWindowsStyle"));` in main.cpp, without success. I guess the QtAssistant docs just aren't clear enough on how can I do this change. Any help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

Could you by any chance be using a Qt package that is compiled without the style? Can you try running [QStyleFactory::keys()](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qstylefactory.html#keys) to verify that the style exists?

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Running the mentioned function I got 3 options, one of them was "Windows". Unfortunately after using that one I got a strange, Windows 98-like appearance, definitively not what I was looking for :) So it's possible that Qt for Linux (I'm using the last version) don't come with Windows 7 style. Do you happen to know how can I get around this situation?

Comment: @Momergil I'm not an expert on the Linux package configurations, but one option certainly would be recompiling Qt from sources.

Comment: The styles often depend on native code on their relevant platforms, so probably you can't have Windows style except on Windows. You definitely can't have Mac OS X style on anything but OS X, for example.

Answer (score 1):

First check out put of `QStyleFactory::keys()`

then set the look by calling

```
qApp->setStyle("Windows");
```

This command will give you windows 98 look. If you want windows vista look you should configure qt sources with `-style-windowsvista` and rebuild all sources.

---

### **UPDATE**

according to http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qstylefactory.html#details qt style is not platform independent. So IT IS IMPOSSIBLE to have that native look in not windows platform. It's worth mentioning that in windows also `Windows SDK` itself is required in order to build sources of Qt otherwise your application will look like windows 98 in windows 7.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Always when I install Qt both in Windows as well as in Linux I never have to "configure" anything; I just download the installer, select the desired packs and install it. It seems that "configure qt sources" doesn't apply in this case, am I right? So could you provide a link or explanation on how would I go if I wanted to "rebuild all sources" with the suggested modification?

Comment: @Momergil When installing Qt there is an option that installs all the sources. You can find them in directory: QTDIR/QT_VERSION/Src/ . In this directory you will find configure file and qt.pro. Then configure sources using http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/configure-options.html . Just search for `-qt-style-<style>` inside that page. for building use this link http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/build-sources.html

Answer (score 1):

It can't be done, since the style's elements are rendered by Windows (or OS X), not by Qt. Qt's style implementation asks the OS libraries to provide bitmaps of those elements. If you wanted to, you could modify the style to use a disk cache for static items. You could then use the style on all platforms. The problem is that these OS-provided bitmaps are a part of the OS and thus non-redistributable.

The only plastform-specific style that at least used to be available everywhere was the old Windows 95 style, in times of Qt 3. I'm not sure what its current status is.